# Building a model matrix for batch correction; problem with linear combinations

Tags: r, batch-normalization

I recently conducted some MASS SPEC for my samples. Each sample was run thrice through the machine. However, there was a large space of time between the first run and the consequent second and third run (both run at the same time), so I would like to conduct a batch effect. My data set looks something like this:

```
Sample      |  Biological Rep 1                 |      Biological Rep 2             |
Condition   |C1      |   C2   |  C3    | C4     | c1     |  C2    |  C3    | C4     |
Tech repeat |1 |2 |2 |1 |2 |2 |1 |2 |2 |1 |2 |2 |1 |2 |2 |1 |2 |2 |1 |2 |2 |1 | 2|2 |
```

The actual dataset looks a bit like this sample, where 1 and 2 represent the technical repeats for diff samples

```
Protein  |1  |2  |2  |1  |2  | 2 | 1 |2   |2 |1  |2  |2  |1  |2   |2  |1  |2 |2 |1   |2   |2  |1  | 2 |2  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Protein1 |19 |34 |45 |10 |23 |22 |16 |92 |28 |11 |29 |23 |10 |223 |22 |32 |22 |34 |56 |46 |85 |11 |32|56 |
Protein2 |12 |24 |23 |11 |24 |23 |15 |21 |65 |19 |21 |26 |41 |872 |57 |75 |23 |29 |53 |83 |92 |21 |62| 29|
```

In the tech repeats, 1 was the technical repeat run first, and 2 represents the second and third repeat that were run at the same time.

The model matrix that I have tried to conduct goes like this:

```
tr1<- as.factor(rep(c(1,2,2),8)) #batch one technical repeat vs 2/3 technical repeat
ms1<- as.factor(c(rep(1,6), rep(2,6), rep(3,6), rep(4,6))) #4 samples, 6 times run 
ex1<- as.factor(c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3), rep(4,3), rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3), rep(4,3))) # 2 biological repeat for each sample, each run thrice
design1<- model.matrix(~ex1 + ms1+tr1)
block <- c(1:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:6)
dupcor = duplicateCorrelation(df, design = design1,  block = block)
fit <- lmFit(df, design1, block = block, correlation = dupcor$consensus)
```

The design matrix looks like this:

```
(Intercept) ex12 ex13 ex14 ms12 ms13 ms14 tr12
1            1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2            1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
3            1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
4            1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
5            1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
6            1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
7            1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
8            1    0    1    0    1    0    0    1
9            1    0    1    0    1    0    0    1
10           1    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
11           1    0    0    1    1    0    0    1
12           1    0    0    1    1    0    0    1
13           1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
14           1    0    0    0    0    1    0    1
15           1    0    0    0    0    1    0    1
16           1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
17           1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1
18           1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1
19           1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
20           1    0    1    0    0    0    1    1
21           1    0    1    0    0    0    1    1
22           1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
23           1    0    0    1    0    0    1    1
24           1    0    0    1    0    0    1    1
```

However, when I run the code it tells me that I have a linear combination in some of my variables

```
Note: design matrix not of full rank (1 coef not estimable).
```

If I remove any variables from the matrix then I run the risk of not accounting for everything. How do I navigate such a problem? Any input would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Maybe other people already know what these functions do. But for those who don't like me, it would be really helpful to see what the first few rows of your design matrix look like.

Comment: have just added what the matrix looks like, hope thats more helpful. thank you so much

Comment: Thanks! Does it solve the problem to replace each variable by that variable but "centered", (that is, replace ex12 with ex12 minus its mean, and so one)?

Comment: That is the model matrix, which is just representing the grouping. I've added a sample of what my dataset looks like! Sorry about that!

Comment: If you remove a variable that is linearly dependent on the others, you run *no* risk of not accounting for anything: the model's fit will be identical.